# How to go to next activity after sending email in Android by clicking one button?

Tags: android

After sending email, I need to go other activity. But I'm going to next activity before sending email. the same question having answer that tells to use startactivityforresult.bt I'm new to Android. I don't know how to use that.

```
public class GetQuoteact extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private ProgressDialog loadDialog;
    Button btsub;
    private String mobilee, namee, emailide, statee, citye, pine, subjecte, streete, success,endresp;

    EditText name_c, mobile_c, emailid_c, state_c, city_c, street_c, pin_c, subject_c;
    public String batter_feat_id,Modelname,Batterytype = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_getquote2);

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }

        name_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mobile_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        emailid_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_id);
        state_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.state);
        city_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
        street_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.street);
        pin_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pincode);
        subject_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
        btsub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_sub);

        Intent in1 = getIntent();
        batter_feat_id = in1.getStringExtra("battery_featuer_idc");
        Modelname = in1.getStringExtra("Model_name");
        Batterytype = in1.getStringExtra("Battery_type");
        btsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                inilize();
                try {
                    if (!validate()) {
                        Toast.makeText(GetQuoteact.this, "Enter necessary details!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        showDialog();
                        onfetch(batter_feat_id);}
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(GetQuoteact.this, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void inilize() {
        namee = name_c.getText().toString();
        mobilee = mobile_c.getText().toString();
        emailide = emailid_c.getText().toString();
        statee = state_c.getText().toString();
        citye = city_c.getText().toString();
        pine = pin_c.getText().toString();
        subjecte = subject_c.getText().toString();
        streete = street_c.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Lastpage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(GetQuoteact.this, "error on sending mail...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void onfetch(String batter_feat_id) {
                  Intent ithh =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                  ithh.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                  String[] to={"abc@gmail.com"};
                  ithh.putExtra(ithh.EXTRA_EMAIL,to);
                  ithh.putExtra(ithh.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Email From JC APP");
                  ithh.putExtra(ithh.EXTRA_TEXT,"Model Name :"+Modelname
                                +"\nBattery Type:"+Batterytype
                                +"\nName :"+namee
                                +"\nContact no :"+mobilee
                                +"\nmailid="+emailide
                                +"\nstate="+statee
                                +"\ncity="+citye
                                +"\narea="+streete
                                +"\npincode="+pine
                                +"\nsubject="+subjecte);
                  startActivityForResult(ithh.createChooser(ithh,"Sent!!!"),1);
            }
              else{
                  Toast.makeText(GetQuoteact.this, "error!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: StartActivityForResult calls back to onActivityResult when the intent returns. What exactly is the problem there?

Comment: how to handle the send button in email?

Answer (score 0):

change your onActivityResult to something like this

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //autocompleteFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               // success open your activity
            } 
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps